# Edit an anchor element that is in a child div inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iFrame on my page that I need to edit the height of an anchor. This anchor is inside a div element that is also nested in another div element. The iframe is sourced from another site (podbean) and they have supplied script to expose class to the global scope.
    https://developers.podbean.com/apidoc/widget#params

This is the script they ask you to include:

```
    var pbs = []; function PB(iframe) {
if (typeof(iframe) == 'string') {
    iframe = document.querySelector(iframe);
}

this._iframe = iframe;
pbs.push(this);

this.eventListeners = {};
}

function searchInPBs(win) {
for (var i in pbs) {
    if (pbs[i]._iframe.contentWindow == win) {
        return i;
    }
}

return -1;
}


PB.prototype.bind = function (event, callback) {
if (!(this.eventListeners[event] instanceof Array)) {
    this.eventListeners[event] = [];
}

this.eventListeners[event].push(callback);
this._iframe.addEventListener(event, callback,false);
};
PB.prototype.unbind = function (event,callback) {
if(callback){
    var index = this.eventListeners[event].indexOf(callback);
    this._iframe.removeEventListener(event, callback,false);
    if(index !== -1){
        this.eventListeners[event].pop(index);
    }
}else{
    if (this.eventListeners[event] instanceof Array) {
        for (var i in this.eventListeners[event]) {
            this._iframe.removeEventListener(event, this.eventListeners[event][i],false);
        }
        this.eventListeners[event] = [];
    }
}

};

PB.prototype.reload = function (url, options) {
//check url is player url
if(url.search('/media/player') === -1){
    throw new Error("url is not active Podbean player");
}

if (typeof(options) === 'object'){
    var urlSplit = url.split('?');
    var urlParamsOrig = urlSplit[1].split('&');
    var urlParams = {};
    for(var k in urlParamsOrig){
        var kv = urlParamsOrig[k].split('=');
        urlParams[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    }

    for(k in options){
        urlParams[k] = options[k];
    }
    var queryString = '?api=1';
    for(k in urlParams){
        queryString += ('&' + k + '=' + urlParams[k]);
    }

    queryString = queryString.trim('&');
    url = urlSplit[0] + queryString;
}
this._iframe.src = url;
};

PB.prototype.play = function () {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.PLAY"});
};
PB.prototype.pause = function () {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.PAUSE"});
};
PB.prototype.next = function () {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.NEXT"});
};
PB.prototype.prev = function () {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.PREV"});
};

PB.prototype.toggle = function () {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.TOGGLE"});
};

PB.prototype.seekTo = function (millisecond) {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.SEEK_TO",value:millisecond});
};
PB.prototype.setVolume = function (volumnNumber) {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.SET_VOLUME",value:volumnNumber});
};
PB.prototype.skip = function (index) {
this._post({action: "PB.Widget.API.SKIP",value:index});
};







//getter
//returns the current volume, in the range of [0, 100].
PB.prototype.getVolume = function(callback){
this._getter('GET_VOLUME',callback);
};
//returns current sound duration in milliseconds.
PB.prototype.getDuration = function(callback){
this._getter('GET_DURATION',callback);
};
//returns current sound position in milliseconds.
PB.prototype.getPosition = function(callback){
    this._getter('GET_POSITION',callback);
};
//whether the widget is paused.
PB.prototype.isPaused = function(callback) {
    this._getter('GET_PAUSED',callback);
};
//returns the list of sound objects.
PB.prototype.getSources = function(callback){
    this._getter('GET_SOURCES',callback);
};
//returns current sound object.
PB.prototype.getCurrentSource = function(callback){
    this._getter('GET_CURRENTSOURCE',callback);
};
//returns the index of current sound.
PB.prototype.getCurrentSourceIndex = function(callback){
    this._getter('GET_CURRENTSOURCEINDEX',callback);
};



PB.prototype._post = function (msg) {
    this._iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(msg, '*');
};

PB.prototype._getter = function (eventName,callback) {
    var self = this;
    var cb = function(event){
        callback(event.data);
        self.unbind('PB.Widget.API.CALLBACK.'+eventName,cb);
    }
    this.bind('PB.Widget.API.CALLBACK.'+eventName,cb);

    this._post({action:'PB.Widget.API.'+eventName});
};

window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.data.event && event.data.event.search('PB.Widget.') != -1
    ) {
        var index = searchInPBs(event.source);
        if (index != -1) {
            var e = new Event(event.data.event);
            e.data = event.data.data;
            pbs[index]._iframe.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the iframe used:

```
<iframe id="multi_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen src="https://www.podbean.com/media/player/multi? playlist=http%3A%2F%2Fplaylist.podbean.com%2F4127923%2Fplaylist_multi.xml&amp;vjs=1&amp;kdsowie31j4k1jlf913=c97955e82971d7fb3b4f8fde2ceb3799e87bdaf9&amp;size=400&amp;skin=13&amp;auto=0&amp;share=1&amp;fonts=Helvetica&amp;download=1&amp;rtl=0" width="100%" height="530"></iframe>
```

I have tried to change this via Javascript but it is not working as I believe it should.

```
var widget = new PB('#multi_iframe');
var ifrm = document.getElementById('multi_iframe');
var win = ifrm.contentWindow;
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
var form = doc.getElementById('player');
function change() {var iframe = widget.form.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.height = "600px"};
```

I just need the a element inside the div id of episode which is in the div id of title to have a style height change.

Comment: Please show the rest of your code

Comment: do you get in the console  an **accessing a cross-origin frame** error?

Comment: I did but using the var widget with new PB to the iframe ID means I don't get it anymore ... I just can't seem to address the anchor I want? It either comes back "getElementsByTagName error as null" or "style is null". I'm obviously not hitting the right element to add the height change